# using delegates in Xcode to perform functions

Tags: swift, xcode

I have 2 view controllers that I am working with each with its own class. In one of the classes there is a function that, among other things, alters various views (changing colors of buttons etc.) in that view controller. In the second view controller I need to make a function that does its own thing inside that view controller as well as call the other function to adjust the views in the first view controller. How do I set up the protocol and delegate to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a very good architecture. Why change a view controller that is not even visible?

Instead, remember what you learned about the MVC (model-view-controller) pattern. You need to abstract the state of a view controller into a **model**, and each view controller is independently responsible of displaying this data in its own way.

So, for example, suppose you want to show a "status", and if it is "critical", the color in one controller should be red, the other controller should just show the word "critical". Both controllers can change this status. In this case you need a variable that holds the status, and both controllers would be able to access and change it.

*(You can start with a global variable, but don't get into the habit of using globals. Later you can explore how to use e.g. a Singleton pattern.)*

Comment: because the function in the second view controller is a "log-out" and it needs to close active things in the app

Comment: Here's a good overview of creating a simple singleton class. https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly: you have VC1 (view controller 1), which presents VC2. When VC2 is active, it may be in a state (or react to an interaction) that it needs to execute a function within VC1.

{Example assume no information needs to be sent back. If information is needed then, change `changedStateFrom` function

```
protocol ChangeStateDelegate {
    func changedStateFrom(_ viewController: UIViewController)
}

class VC1: UIViewController, ChangedStateDelegate {
    // Here is where you present VC2
    let vc = VC2()
    let vc.delegate = self

    // ChangedStateDelegate
    func changedStateFrom(_ viewController: UIViewController){
        // call whatever function in VC1 you need
    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController {
    var delegate: ChangedStateDelegate?

    func foo(){
        // Where ever VC2 reacts to a state change and needs to inform VC1, execute this
        self.delegate?.changedStateFrom(self)
    }
}
```